# What is the best way to create a superuser in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am working on a flask application which I need to create different types of user roles using a superuser. What is the best way to create a superuser? Some of ways that I am thinking is:

1. Create a [custom command](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#custom-commands) and execute the command in production.

   ```
   import click
   from flask import Flask

   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.cli.command("create-superuser")
   @click.argument("name")
   def create_superuser(name):
       ...
   ```
2. Create a function and execute before first request.

   ```
   @app.before_first_request
   def init_db():
       db.create_all()
       insert_superuser()
   ```
3. Or just sql insert a superuser in the database.

If I am doing this wrong or this is a bad practice to do in production please tell me. I am still new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By the way, I'm sorry but you tagged your question `flask_restful`, and I really think everyone should use `flask_restplus` (being now `flask_restx`, forked due to change of maintainers).**

*I could change the tags, but I want to leave you the choice of doing it*

This is what pleases you the most. There is no best way. It depends of your use-case. However, I dislike the 2nd method (before_first_request).

1. The custom command

If you want to put this task in the hand of a person, you can use this. People will come to someone that will add them or not on the admin side.

2. You can use the `@app.before_request()` decorator so that the action is performed each and every time, but do not set the database each and everytime you light up the app. Use a database, and it leads us to the 3rd one.
3. Superuser in database (password hashed with sha256).

Usually, if the system is in production, you don't want to mess with the admin too much.

There is another way : [The JWT token](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: Would you like to expand on JWT use?

Comment: I'm a little bit tired, but I think this [flask documentation with jwt tokens](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/) should be cool :) The hello_world is simple !

Comment: How it helps to create superuser?

Comment: It is just another way to handle the admin rights. Not by a properly defined ""user"", but a sort of "secret key" that allows the person that has it to act like an admin.

Comment: connexion is much better than restplus if you need to add many custom fields to your swagger spec...

Comment: @IMCoins May be you missed that topic starter would like to have different classes of users, which would have their own passwords

Comment: @Z4-tier I will look at that for sure in the next days

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Sorry for the flask_restful tag, I will check the flask_restx later tonight.

Thanks for the inputs, I asked because I dont know which method is the right way. I will experiment and find which one works best on my use-case. I am leaning on the first method to do a version of Django's `manage.py createsuperuser`

And btw Im using flask-praetorian for assigning rights for each user accounts.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options here-

1. Have a CLI command for adding the user, like you are doing. I find that most projects go this route, and that it works pretty well as long as you can run the CLI on a system with the appropriate config. Generally speaking it might make sense to expand that CLI to also include things like password resets.
2. Have a "First run" most where the application displays a form asking for information. This is how things like Github Enterprise or Wordpress tend to work, but there is a small threat where a user who knows you are deploying can beat you to the web interface. This can be mitigated by having the first run script log a URL with a security token in it, so only someone with access to the logs can start the configuration project. If you're not deploying to customers though this is more complicated than needed.
3. Have users get created based off of environmental variables. This route is particularly useful for when you're creating developer environments, as it means the devs don't have to run through extra steps when getting setup. It is a bad idea to do in production though.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for the response and inputs. I might experiment on the methods to know which one works best on my use-case. I might do a version of Django's `manage.py createsuperuser`